# How to limit spans depth in opentelemetry?

Tags: trace, open-telemetry

I'm using opentelemetry with autoconfiguration. I've added some methods for tracing with `otel.instrumentation.methods.include` option. I have a lot of methods calling other methods and so on. But I don't need them all in tracing. I want to configure spans depth, i.e. log only parent spans, or log parent span and first child. And when it's required showing all spans. How I can configure it in autoconfiguring opentelemetry?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not supported (looking at the [config options](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java/blob/main/sdk-extensions/autoconfigure/README.md#span-limits) and confirming with the SIG Java). Would be worth it to create a feature request.